# docker проблема с доступам к файлам на windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox

При запуске docker-compose up -d --build проходит загрузка контейнеров db и adminer а контейнер web не грузится из-за отсутствия директории. `ERROR: for backend  Cannot start service backend: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:449: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\\"/c/project/dcvisitors/docker/conf/nginx/backend.conf\\\" to rootfs \\\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b166c7ef849ee3f1631f2d4abd8b47bcd0d42c035808fa27a3fea644b60c9/merged/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\"": unknown: Are you tryin`
Директория есть, доступ у пользователя есть. Запускал Docker и VM от имени админа, менял права доступа к папкам и файлам. Переустанавливал.
Для default машины в VirtualBox прописал папку с проектом [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую Windows 10 pro Сборка 19042.804 и Docker Toolbox 19.03.1 с Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в NDIS draver, который по версии не подходит к моей windows 10 в сборке 19042 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/overview-of-ndis-versions). Проверка следующем путем "Панель управления"->"Диспетчер устройств"->"Системные устройства"->"NDIS". Просто обновить не получилось. Решение получилось такое:

1. Удалить VirtualBox
2. Удалить Docker Toolbox
3. Удалить в ручную драйвер "Панель управления"->"Диспетчер устройств"->"Системные устройства"->"NDIS"
4. Произвести установку от имени Администратора Docker Toolbox с VirtualBox
5. Запуск от имени Администратора VirtualBox
6. Запуск от имени Администратора Docker Terminal
7. После загрузки Docker зайти в VirtualBox и для машины прописать общую папку с проектом
8. Перезапустить машину в VirtualBox и перезапустить Docker

После данных действий все заработало отлично!